# Python: Extract video stream link from a page

Tags: python, video-streaming

I wonder if there is a way to extract a video stream link from a page.
For example in Youtube and in the page http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=he5fpsmH_2g extract the actual download link of the video and download it, just like what [VideoGet](http://nuclear-coffee.com/VideoGet) does.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the src-code for [clive](http://clive.sourceforge.net/) to see how it can be done from a script.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is written in Perl. And I don't understand a bit of it.